# Use [DB] for Mongodb with shell

Tags: mongodb

I am researching now the simple "use" command for the mongo command. Please help me.

I just want save the my query in a file, but before that i need to connect to a certain database. For that i tried to find a "use" command like in sql, but could not find anything.

I just want to execute something like

```
mongo ....--use [db] --eval 'db.find' > save.query
```

Answer (score 0):

In your question, you didn't specify what platform you're using, are you using Linux? Windows? Anyway, if you want to use the command line for mongo db then I would recommend to use the mongodb shell. Download the mongodb shell https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/shell and select what platform you're using.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongodb-shell/run-commands/#mongosh-usage

That sais you have `use <database>` command

Answer (score 0):

I just got it. You can just add the database name:

```
mongo [dbname] --host etc.
```

and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

This is the easiest way in linux:

**Option 1 ( command line params )**

```
 echo "db.exampleollection.find({}).forEach(function(d){printjson(d)})" | mongo --quiet exampledatabase --host "examplehost" --port "examplePort" --authenticationDatabase=admin -u "exampleuser" -p "examplepassword"  > output.json
```

Explained:

Send the command you need to execute  via echo to the mongo  shell and redirect the output to the result file.
Add the option --quiet to suppress the shell printed info
You can provide the database directly in as comman line argument.

**Option 2 : same way but URI format:**

```
 echo "show collections" | mongo "mongodb://user:pass@host:port/database?authSource=admin"  --quiet
```